# How to pass all text of input selected row into action?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

i have this view in my project.

I want to get the text of input in each row that is selected.

How to pass all text of input selected row into action

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="45%">Select</th>
            <th width="45%">User Name</th>
            <th width="5%">Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.TypeList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name=checklist" id="checklist"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Extradecription"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

my Actions. How can I have the corresponding values of text and checkbox for the Selected rows

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(repository.GetUser());
    }


    public IActionResult Save(int[] checklist,string[] Extradecription)
    {
        repository.Save(checklist,Extradecription);
        return View(repository.GetUser());
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to get values to link or get all values into an array?

Comment: get all values into an array (Only selected rows)

Comment: Can you show your controller action code please?

Comment: yes. update my question

Comment: Check my answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to get two different arrays as you have showed in you controller-action code, there will be a trouble with text for non selected items, the array for check boxes will bind as expected but for descriptions will be different, just to be clear, check the following example:

Assuming We have a list with tree options:

- 100 - Foo
- 200 - Bar
- 300 - Zaz

If We set the following selection for items:

- Foo, a
- Zaz, c

If We take a look on the request, this is the raw request:

```
checklist = 100,300
Extradecription = a,null,c
```

So, the trouble is avoid to bind null descriptions for non selected options, this is complicated, in that case I recommend to you a clear solution:

1. Create a model to create entity process
2. Create a model for option
3. Add a list of option model in create entity model
4. Initialize the model to create a new entity
5. Render inputs in view using asp-for tag
6. Retrieve the request to create a new entity

I'll assume the name of models and properties to show how to bind a typed array in your request, change the names according to your scenario.

Create entity model:

```
public class CreateEntity
{
    public CreateEntity()
    {
        Items = new List<SelectedItem>();
    }

    // Step 3
    [BindProperty]
    public List<SelectedItem> Items { get; set; }

    // Another properties
}
```

Model for option:

```
public class SelectedItem
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public int Code { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

Rendering the options list:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
{
    <input asp-for="@Model.Items[i].IsSelected" />@Model.Items[i].Name
    <input asp-for="@Model.Items[i].Desc" />
    <br/>
}
```

The GET and POST actions in controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult CreateOption()
{
    // Set the items list
    var model = new CreateEntity
    {
        Items = new List<SelectedItem>
        {
            new SelectedItem{ Code = 100, Name = "Foo" },
            new SelectedItem{ Code = 200, Name = "Bar" },
            new SelectedItem{ Code = 300, Name = "Zaz" }
        }
    };

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateOption(CreateEntity form)
{
    // Retrieve only selected items
    var query = form.Items.Where(item => item.IsSelected == true).ToList();

    return View();
}
```

If you want to know more about check boxes in Razor pages, please check this link: [Checkboxes in a Razor Pages Form](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes)

Please let me know if this answer is useful.